# Elasticsearch does not sort on double field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am querying index in ES using below code

```
def cat_results_tmp(response,field):
    results=[]
    for hit in response['hits']['hits']:
        result_tuple = (
                        hit["_source"][field]
                        )
        results.append(result_tuple)
    return results       

def categories3(cat_sort_field="", sort_order=""):
    client = Elasticsearch([{'host':localhost,'port':9200}])
    response = client.search( \
    index="cat_test", \
    body={\
       "query": { "match_all": {} }
       ,"sort" : [
         { cat_sort_field: {"order" : sort_order} }]
        ,"size":100
        }
        )
    print(response)
    response3=cat_results_tmp(response,cat_sort_field)
    return response3

#fail if the field used for sorting is double
print(categories3("fielda","asc"))
print(categories3("fieldb","desc"))
```

I tried with multiple fields for my index and all double fields can be sorted, I get `'sort': [0]` for the printed response, while float fields work fine.

Also double fields cannot be changed into float fields with mapping after indexing. How to solve this except for create a custom mapping while indexing?

Comment: Please share mappings + parameters you use to call categories3. Did you try the same request using CURL or head plugin?

Comment: @LeBigCat Updated in my question. I did not custom mapping the index, straightly logstashed it with jdbc connection. Field type checked with `_mappings`. I just tried in Kibana console and also failed to sort double fields.

Comment: Really strange, witch version do you use?

Comment: @LeBigCat I use 7.3.1